# How to extend a matrix in Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix

I've been trying to create a function that returns a given matrix and adds one row & column whose digits are the sum of the numbers in the row/column next to
 the digits the sum of the numbers in the column...

E.g.

```
(1 2
 3 4)
```

to

```
(1 2 3
 3 4 7
4 6 10)
```

My first thought was something like

```
> extend1 :: Int -> Array (Int,Int) Int
> extend1 ((a,b),(c,d))  = n where
>                 n = array ((a,b),(c,d),(n,n))
```

because I have to use "array". Now I don't know how to go on. Is it okay or totally wrong?

Comment: Most of the matrix libraries (to my knowledge) use fixed-size arrays, so in order to extend one, you would have to construct one of the correct size and copy the contents of the original array to the new one.  This is essentially what you're doing here, although this won't compile because you've reused `n` as both the array and an element in the array, so this won't type check or make any mathematical sense.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be better to use
     n = array ((a,b),(c,d),(m,m))
or something?

Comment: You'll still have to define what `m` is.  Haskell can't automatically figure out what you want in those locations.  You're going to have to align the type signature as well, what you're currently passing in is a value of type `((Int, Int), (Int, Int))`, which is not `Array (Int, Int) Int` or `Int`.

Comment: Also, what is your use case for using `Array` for this as opposed to normal Haskell lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should understand how to interface with haskell arrays. The `Array` datatype is found in `Data.Array`, so for full details, look at the docs for that module.

Note that I omit the `Ix i` constraint you would find on all of these functions. It isn't really important for this situation.

`bounds :: Array i e -> (i, i)`: This function returns the min and max indices of the array. For a 1D array, these are just numbers. For a 2D array, it the the top left and bottom right corners (for a matrix).

`array :: (i, i) -> [(i, e)] -> Array i e`: This function creates an array from a min/max pair for the bounds, and a list of associations; that is, a map from indices to values. Your intial example can be written as `array ((0,0),(1,1)) [((0,0),1),((0,1),2),((1,0),3),((1,1),4)]`

`assocs :: Array i e -> [(i, e)]`: This is the 'opposite' of `array`. So, `arr == array (bounds arr) (assocs arr)`.

Now the function:

```
extendArray :: Num e => Array (Int, Int) e -> Array (Int, Int) e
extendArray arr = 
    let
      arr' = assocs arr
      ((xMin, yMin), (xMax, yMax)) = bounds arr
      newCol = [ ((n, yMax + 1) , sum [ v | ((x,_),v) <- arr', x == n] ) | n <- [xMin .. xMax]]
      newRow = [ ((xMax + 1, n) , sum [ v | ((_,y),v) <- arr', y == n] ) | n <- [yMin .. yMax]]
      newCorner = [((xMax + 1, yMax + 1), sum $ map snd arr')]
      newArr = array ((xMin, yMin), (xMax + 1, yMax + 1)) (arr' ++ newCol ++ newRow ++ newCorner)

    in newArr
```

Lets break down what is happening here. The first two lines in the `let` statement should be self-explanatory by now. The third line, `newCol`, is where the magic happens. It uses list comprehensions so if you are unfamiliar with them, see [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out).

`n <- [xMin .. xMax]`: This part gets all the possible x-values.

`[ v | ((x,_),v) <- arr', x == n]`: This reads as, for all values in the list `arr'` such that the x-coordinate of the index is equal to n, return the value at that coordinate.

`((n, yMax + 1) , sum ...` Create a new index, whose column is 1 plus the maximum of the old array (so 1 column to the right of the old matrix), whose row is `n` and whose value is the sum of the previous line (ie - the sum of all the values in row `n`).

`newRow` works the same way, but rows and columns reversed.

`newCorner` gets all the values in the matrix, computes their sum, and places this value at the appropriate index in the new array.

`newArr` simply combines all the steps into a new array. Obviously the bounds will grow by one in each direction. The associations of the new array are going to include all the old associations, as well as the new ones we have computed.

So:

```
>let x = array ((0,0),(1,1)) [((0,0),1),((0,1),2),((1,0),3),((1,1),4)]
>x
array ((0,0),(1,1)) [((0,0),1),((0,1),2),((1,0),3),((1,1),4)]
>extendArray x
array ((0,0),(2,2)) [((0,0),1),((0,1),2),((0,2),3),((1,0),3),((1,1),4),((1,2),7),((2,0),4),((2,1),6),((2,2),10)]
```

Note that this implementation isn't efficient (it is however simple). In `newRow`, we traverse the entire matrix `xMax - xMin` times (once for each `n` value). Since `assocs` always returns elements in the same order (rows from left to right, columns from up to down) it would be better to split the list `arr'` into lists each with length `yMax - yMin`; this would get us a list of the rows. But I will leave this optimization to you.

Answer (score 4):

Using your representation of tuples and without much an eye for generalities, here's a solution to your problem.

```
type Square2 a = ((a,a), (a,a))
type Square3 a = ((a,a,a), (a,a,a), (a,a,a))

extend1 :: Num a => Square2 a -> Square3 a
extend1 ((a,b), (c,d)) = 
  ( (a,  b,  ab  )
  , (c,  d,  cd  )
  , (ac, bd, abcd) ) 

  where
    ab   = a  + b
    cd   = c  + d
    ac   = a  + c
    bd   = b  + d
    abcd = ab + cd
```

Note how I use variable definitions culled both from the pattern of the input and the definitions in the `where` clause. Also notice how I destruct and consume the input while building an entirely new output---some of the elements are reused, but the structure itself is destroyed. Finally note how I chose the type inside of the tuples to be constant and constrained by the `Num` typeclass which allows me use of `(+)` for addition.

A similar function, generalized and using `Array`s has a type like

```
extend1A :: Num a => Array (Int,Int) a -> Array (Int, Int) a
```

where we've lost the ability to know the exact size of the `Array`s but it's indicated that our function takes one `Array` of some size and returns another `Array` that is indexed identically and containing the same `Num`-constrained type.

The `array` function takes as its first argument a set of bounds. We need to update those based on the `bounds` of the input array

```
extend1A ary0 = array bounds1 ... where
  ((minX, minY), (maxX, maxY)) = bounds ary0
  (maxX1, maxY1) = (succ maxX, succ maxY)
  bounds1 = ((minX, minY, (maxX1, maxY1))
```

Then `array` takes a list of "assocs" as its second argument. We can treat any `Array ix a` as being equivalent (roughly) to a list of assocs `[(ix, a)]` which list values stating "at the index `ix` the value is `a`". To do this we must know the `bounds` of the `ix` type which we managed just previously.

To update an array using the information from an old one, we can modify the `assocs` of the old array to include new information. Concretely, this means that `extend1A` looks a bit like

```
extend1A ary0 = array bounds1 (priorInformation ++ extraInformation) where
  priorInformation = assocs ary0
  extraInformation = ...
  ((minX, minY), (maxX, maxY)) = bounds ary0
  (maxX1, maxY1) = (succ maxX, succ maxY)
  bounds1 = ((minX, minY, (maxX1, maxY1))
```

If `extraInformation` were empty (`[]`) then `extend1A ary` would be equal to `ary` on all indicies in range of the input `ary` and `undefined` on all outside of its range. We need to fill in `extraInformation` with the summation information.

```
extend1A ary0 = array bounds1 (priorInformation ++ extraInformation) where
  priorInformation = assocs ary0 
  extraInformation = xExtension ++ yExtension ++ totalExtension
  xExtension = ...
  yExtension = ...
  totalExtension = ...
  ((minX, minY), (maxX, maxY)) = bounds ary0
  (maxX1, maxY1) = (succ maxX, succ maxY) 
  bounds1 = ((minX, minY, (maxX1, maxY1))
```

If we think of extending the array in three pieces, the `xExtension` marked by `ab` and `cd` in `extend1`, the `yExtension` marked by `ac` and `bd` in `extend1` and the `totalExtension` marked by `abcd` in `extend1` we can then compute each part in turn.

`totalExtension` is easiest--it's just the sum of the "value component" of each `(i,a)` pair in `priorInformation`. It could also be the sum of the "value component" of either `xExtension` or `yExtension`, but in order to be as obviously correct as possible, we'll pick the first choice and install that at the lower-right corner.

```
extend1A ary0 = array bounds1 (priorInformation ++ extraInformation) where
  priorInformation = assocs ary0
  extraInformation = xExtension ++ yExtension ++ totalExtension
  sumValues asscs = sum (map snd asscs)
  xExtension = ...
  yExtension = ...
  totalExtension = [((maxX1, maxY1), sumValues priorInformation)]
  ((minX, minY), (maxX, maxY)) = bounds ary0
  (maxX1, maxY1) = (succ maxX, succ maxY)
  bounds1 = ((minX, minY), (maxX1, maxY1))
```

Note that we can use the `where` clause to define new functions like `sumValues` which will show up over and over.

Then we can compute the extensions as list comprehensions over the `priorInformation`. We need to collect a particular kind of sum over the old assocs---summing over all the values where one index is fixed.

```
xExtension = [( (maxX1, yix)
              , sumValues (filter (\((_, j), _) -> j == yix) priorInformation)
              )
             | yix <- [minY .. maxY]
             ]

yExtension = [( (xix, maxY1)
              , sumValues (filter (\((i, _), _) -> i == xix) priorInformation)
              )
             | xix <- [minX .. maxX]
             ]
```

And then we're done. It's not efficient, but all the pieces work together.

```
extend1A ary0 = array bounds1 (priorInformation ++ extraInformation) where
  priorInformation = assocs ary0
  extraInformation = xExtension ++ yExtension ++ totalExtension
  xExtension = [( (maxX1, yix)
                , sumValues (filter (\((_, j), _) -> j == yix) priorInformation)
                )
               | yix <- [minY .. maxY]
               ]
  yExtension = [( (xix, maxY1)
                , sumValues (filter (\((i, _), _) -> i == xix) priorInformation)
                )
               | xix <- [minX .. maxX]
               ]
  totalExtension = [((maxX1, maxY1), sum xExtension)]
  ((minX, minY), (maxX, maxY)) = bounds ary0
  (maxX1, maxY1) = (succ maxX, succ maxY)
  bounds1 = ((minX, minY), (maxX1, maxY1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using hmatrix:

```
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Util(col,row)

m = (2><2) [1 , 2
           ,3 , 4] :: Matrix Double


extend m = fromBlocks [[m ,sr]
                      ,[sc, s]]
  where
    sr = col $ map sumElements (toRows m)
    sc = row $ map sumElements (toColumns m)
    s  = scalar (sumElements sr)


main = do
    print m
    print $ extend m


(2><2)
 [ 1.0, 2.0
 , 3.0, 4.0 ]
(3><3)
 [ 1.0, 2.0,  3.0
 , 3.0, 4.0,  7.0
 , 4.0, 6.0, 10.0 ]
```

Comment: `hmatrix` is powerful and interesting!